# Postgres sql show a specific string in result based on integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have table with cars and color on said cars. Color is shown as an integer, but i want to map it in the *select* query so that the respective color is shown instead. A mapping table doesn´t exist and I don´t have write access to the database so I can`t create a mapping table. The query is only meant for a dashboard which only allows SQL queries.

I have a table like this:

```
| **Color**   | **Car**    |     
| 1       | BMW    |    
| 2       | Nissan   |   
| 1       | Tesla   |
```

And this query

```
SELECT "Color", count(*)
FROM "Cars"
GROUP BY "Color"
```

Which will give this result:

```
| Color | Count |    
|  1  |   2  |        
|  2  |   1  |
```

But what I want is this:

```
| Color | Count |    
| white  |   2  |    
| green  |   1  |
```

How can i write a query like this?

Comment: Join to the `colors` table that is the reference table with the correct name.

Comment: That would be the optimal. But said table doesn´t exist and I don´t have write access to the database so I can`t create a mapping table. Updated question with information

Comment: Gordon was not claiming you have to use a mapping table, but you should use [JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-join.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really do not have a reference table, then you will need to do something like this:

```
with color_names as (
  select car,
         color,
         case color
           when 1 then 'green'
           when 2 then 'white'
           else 'unknown'
         end as color_name
    from your_table
)
select color_name, count(*) 
  from color_names
 group by color_name;
```

Comment: Had to make a small change, with color_names as ( ....

Answer (score 2):

Ok so "said table doesn´t exist and I don´t have write access". There is a very simple solution here: Go talk to your DBA and ask for it. One of the **stupidest** ideas in IT today is developers not talking to DBAs (almost as stupid as DBA not responding to developers). Contrary to popular belief **you are on the same team**.  
However, in the event she/he doesn't respond (thus you unable to accomplish @Gordon goal of not repeating logic) but there is a work around - at least until the DBA comes to their sinces. You create a template CTE which can be pulled into queries as needed.

```
with color_names (id, name) as
     ( values (1,'White')
            , (2,'Green')
     )
```

Make sure this is stored in a location accessible to the entire team. This can the be pulled in whenever needed. 

Then again, on second thought, you're a developer so develop: create a function that returns a table. You can then use this function almost exactly as if it were at table and it has a massive benefit - *a single point of maintenance* for all queries using it. Not quite the same as just updating a table, but massively better than having to update multiple queries.

Both are incorporated in [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ab1ee0c14b39b8e514e2ca45bfc8971c).